# Gradle TestNG results output

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, testng

I can't seem to figure out how to configure log output and results folders for Gradle TestNG runs.

First, Gradle picks `$project_dir/build/reports/tests` by default for HTML report output. How do I change this default location? I tried setting `testReportDir` in `build.gradle` to no avail. Specifying a map in call to useTestNG(), e.g.

```
test {
   if (runTest) {
      // enable TestNG support (default is JUnit)
      useTestNG {
         outputDirectory = file("$buildDir/test-output")
      }
   }
}
```

does not work as well.

Second, I tried using TestNG's Reporter for some additional logging, e.g:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
   parseFile();
   Reporter.log("File parsed");
   Assert.assertTrue(...);
}
```

But I can't seem to find the logs! Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `testReportDir` property is read-only. You'll need to set `Project.testReportDirName`. You should be able to enable test logging like so.

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Comment: I tried setting testReportDirName, it had no effect. As for showStandardStreams - i do get the logs in standard output, but how do i redirect them to a file? Or preferably to the Gradle test report in HTML format?

Comment: Take note, the `testReportDirName` is a property on the Project, not the Test task. Ensure you place it outside your `test { ...}` closure. Also, try making it an absolute path `testReportDirName = "${buildDir}/myReportDir"`. Anything logged to standard out (or standard error) is included in both the HTML report (by click on the individual test class, then the 'Standard Output' tab) or in the XML and binary files in your 'build/test-results' directory.