# Gradle TestNG Task is not create test-output folder

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, testng

I just start working with Gradle on Test Automation.

Here we have a problem that test-out folder is not created when we triggered Gradle Task.

**Right click > Run As TestNG** , it works fine the out-put folder is created.

But when we **execute Gradle Task**. this folder is not created.

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'unit'

    }
    ignoreFailures = true
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

}


task ParallelTestExecution(type: Test) {

    useTestNG() {

      options.parallel = 'methods' //modes: methods, tests, classes or instances.
      options.threadCount = 3

      includeGroups 'SMOKE','FUNCTIONAL'
      useDefaultListeners = false

      listeners << 'com.systemtest.testreporter.ExtentReporterNG'
      listeners << 'com.systemtest.testreporter.TestListener'
      listeners << 'com.systemtest.testreporter.RetryListener'  


    }
    ignoreFailures = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle TestNG tasks default creates a report in `build/reports` directory.

Comment: i dont need reports, I need xml files under test-output folder

Comment: Please refer to this SO thread : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26125490/679824