# Why can't I see exceptions thrown with TestNG?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I'm using TestNG with gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.testng',  name: 'testng', version: '6.11'
```

I'm using IntelliJ to run my tests.  However, when one of my methods throws an exception, it doesn't show me what exception was thrown:

[image: Failed test]

The `startDb` method threw an exception, and was correctly marked as failed, but I can't find any way for me to actually see the exception that was thrown (without wrapping the method in a try-catch).

Method:

[image: StartDb Method]

The specific method doesn't show anything either:

[image: Specific method results]

Is this supposed to be occurring?  How am I supposed to debug why tests are failing if I don't get any information from TestNG?

Comment: Have you filled an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/? It is the proper place to reports such issues instead of SO.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I'm not sure if this is a jetbrains issue or a TestNG.  I've filed several bugs there, but I'm not sure what the cause is.

Comment: Are you using Expected Exception in the @Test annotation? They will catch all exceptions defined there and no info will be printed.

Comment: I have my method in the question.  Furthermore, if I *did* have expected exceptions, the test would pass, not fail.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, TestNG doesn't show output unless the following is set in gradle:

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Comment: In that case, it's more a gradle "issue" which doesn't have an appropriate configuration (or IntelliJ which doesn't override them).

Answer (score 1):

TestNG captures test classes' console output, including any stacktraces, into xml files. By default they are under the `test-output` directory.

Comment: Apparently, on gradle, [it goes in the `build/reports` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257967/gradle-testng-task-is-not-create-test-output-folder), and while I *do* have some html files there, they are all blank with no information.